# Find unique sub-strings and preserve sequence

Tags: python, arrays, string

I'm trying to write a method that takes a string, for example a DNA string and outputs the number with the sub string and preserves the sequence.

For example:

```
>>dna = AABBBGGGKKDDDD
>>substring(dna) #some method
>>2A3B3G2K4D
```

I'm guessing I can have an empty array, and then create a for loop that iterates through each and every letter and if it's the same letter, it does a count and then adds the letter in the end. I'm just not sure how to syntactically write it out. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I would recommend that you give that idea a shot and see where it leads :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example.

```
dna = 'AABBBGGGKKDDDD'


def get_sequence(dna):
    sequence = ''
    previous_c = ''
    count = 0
    for c in dna:
        if c == previous_c:
            count += 1
        else:
            if len(previous_c) > 0:
                sequence += '{}{}'.format(count, previous_c)
            count = 1
            previous_c = c
    if count > 0:
        sequence += '{}{}'.format(count, previous_c)
    return sequence


print(get_sequence('A'))
print(get_sequence(''))
print(get_sequence(dna))
```

Output:

```
1A

2A3B3G2K4D
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I had in mind, I wasn't thinking of creating a separate variable for the previous character

Answer (score 2):

[`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) works perfectly for this task:

```
from itertools import groupby

def get_sequence(dna):
    return ''.join(str(len(tuple(g))) + k for k, g in groupby(dna))

print(get_sequence('AABBBGGGKKDDDD'))
# 2A3B3G2K4D
```